# USB Drive at the same location on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, truenas, udev

I have a number of USB drives that are attached to a FreeNAS server. These are then used as offline backup targets. One problem is that the order that the drives are plugged into matters.

On a Linux based system, I would use udev rules to ensure that the Drive ends up at a common /dev device. Is there an equivalent method for FreeNAS/FreeBSD?

If there isn't, is there a better way to sync a dataset to a USB drive within FreeNAS that is not dependent on a constant disk location?

Comment: What's wrong with mounting via uuid/gptid or label?

Comment: We have a couple of drives in rotation, but having the same label is probably feasible.